# Oracle19c - Issue using db-link to GCP with Simba Driver

Tags: google-bigquery, odbc, simba

In CASE 2, simba driver tries to find remote table in US location and not in UE location where it is.
Same problem using version 3.0.0 of Simba driver.
All Simba drivers versions work if remote table is on GCP dataset with location US.

**CASE1: Simba Driver Version 2.1.11**
Driver Simba: configuration file: odbc.ini e odbcinst.ini
Oracle Database: configuration file: tnsnames.ora, listener.ora,initbq.oraand creation of oracle db-link "BQ".
GCP: Catalog on GCP project with EU location.
TEST: Connect with sqlplus and query run on GCP remote table ( project with UE location ).

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Sep 5 11:39:52 2023
Version 19.16.0.0.0
Copyright (c) 1982, 2022, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password:Last Successful login time: Tue Sep 05 2023 11:38:45 +02:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.16.0.0.0

SQL> select "contract_id" from "profiling_datamodel"."contracts"@BQ;

### contract_id

```
      3
      1
      5
      2
      4
```

**CASE2: Simba Driver Version 2.5.2**

Driver Simba: configuration file: odbc.ini e odbcinst.ini
Oracle Database: configuration file: tnsnames.ora, listener.ora,initbq.oraand creation of oracle db-link "BQ".
GCP: Catalog on GCP project with EU location.
TEST: Connect with sqlplus and query run on GCP remote table ( project with UE location ).

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Sep 5 10:39:25 2023
Version 19.16.0.0.0
Copyright (c) 1982, 2022, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password: Last Successful login time: Tue Sep 05 2023 10:39:46 +02:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.16.0.0.0

SQL> select count(*) from "profiling_datamodel"."contracts"@BQ

select count(*) from "profiling_datamodel"."contracts"@BQ

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-28500: connection from ORACLE to a non-Oracle system returned this message:
[Simba][BigQuery] (100) Error interacting with REST API: Access Denied: Table
ita-da-dev:profiling_datamodel.contracts: User does not have permission to query table ita-da-dev:profiling_datamodel.contracts, or perhaps it does not exist in location US. {42000,NativeErr = 100}
ORA-02063: preceding 2 lines from BQ

Someone have some idea on how I can solve this issue?

Best Regards,
Simone

I already create a temporary dataset on BQ and I tried also to force AllowLargeResults=1 and LargeResultsDataSetId=temporary_dataset into odbc.ini file but the issue still occurs.